# Convert svn to git using git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, dvcs

I am attempting to convert a svn repository to git.  The layout of the svn repo has the branch/tag/trunk.  When I do the conversion to git (git svn clone) I have the exact same layout.  I get the branch, tag and trunk folders.

I have noticed that many of the recommendations for converting to git state we must clean up the tags to make them git tags.  They state that the tags and branches are viewed as remote branches, tags are prefixed with "tag/".

However my ref/remotes folder is completely empty.  I see all of my tags located under my "tag' folder.  Along with the underlying folder structure and classes.

After a git svn clone what should my git repo look like?  Should it in fact have the tags/branch/trunk structure just like my svn repo?  Any idea on why I am not getting the tags to come across as others have?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the --stdlayout option. Then it will correctly create branches and tags for you.

Comment: Thanks I will kick off another one and try with that option.